# Need an easy way to remove duplicates of nested tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

I am currently working with a script that has lists that looks like this:

```
example = [ ((2,1),(0,1)), ((0,1),(2,1)), ((2,1),(0,1)) ]
```

Now turning this list to a set returns:

```
set( [ ((2,1),(0,1)), ((0,1),(2,1)) ] )
```

For my purposes I need to recognize these tuples as being equal as well. I dont care about retaining the order. All solutions I can think of is really messy so if anyone has any idea I would be gratefull.

Comment: Would `((1,2),(1,0))` also be considered a match?

Comment: No, that wouldnt be a match. The tuples are representing subsets of directed edges in a graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [10]: set(tuple(sorted(elt)) for elt in example)
Out[10]: set([ ((0, 1), (2, 1)) ])
```

Comment: i like this better because it reflects an unordered but possible duplicate basic element of the set.

Comment: +1. This is more robust than my solution for input where the items of the original list contain duplicates among their items (though less efficient for items of huge size).

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you may be off using frozensets instead of tuples.

```
>>> x = [((2, 1), (0, 1)), ((0, 1), (2, 1)), ((2, 1), (0, 1))]
>>> x
[((2, 1), (0, 1)), ((0, 1), (2, 1)), ((2, 1), (0, 1))]
>>> set(frozenset(ts) for ts in x)
set([frozenset([(0, 1), (2, 1)])])
```

Comment: If `x=[ ((2, 1), (2, 1)) ]`, `frozenset(ts)` would be `frozenset([(2,1)])`. I'm not sure if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: That sitation shouldnt come up in the script I'm working with, but thanks for the head's up. I will look into the frozenset solution.

Answer (score 0):

First transform all elements to sets too. Then make a set of the whole list.

Comment: Mike Graham was faster adding code identical to mine, so look up his solution.